# Plugin SVN folder structure

Tags: plugin-development, directory, publish, svn

I´m used to git, but i am new to svn. Do i need to re-create the svn folder structure (trunk, assets, tags) in my local repo, or are the files automatically "sorted into folders" when i push my plugin to the wordpress directory?

My current setup:

```
/myplugin/index.php
/myplugin/readme.txt
/myplugin/assets/screenshot-1.png
```

Thanks for answering, i don´t want to push to the plugin directory without being sure about the structure.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, figured it out: my first pull from svn was not successful, on second try, the directories are there.